# Why java String treat some UTF-8 symbols as several characters

Tags: java, string, utf-8

I'm trying to cover utf-8 symbols but java String converts 1 symbol to several sometimes. Writing it to file and displaying in editor works well, but I need to check valid java identifiers which can be written even in 4 bytes like "**f0 93 81 98**" for next diapason:

> U+0080-U+07FF (110xxxxx 10xxxxxx)

String split it to 2 symbols. 
So question is how to get correct string from utf-8 bytes array. Here is my code sample:

```
    byte[] test = {0, 0};
    int tmp;//use tmp int to avoid negative pointer bit mess
    for (int a = 12; a < 14; a++) {//110x mask
        for (int b = 0; b < 16; b++) {
            tmp = a << 4;
            tmp |= b;
            test[0] = (byte) tmp;
            for (int c = 8; c < 14; c++) {//10xx mask
                for (int d = 0; d < 16; d++) {
                    tmp = c << 4;
                    tmp |=d;
                    test[1] = (byte) tmp;

                    String symbol = new String(test, "UTF-8");
                    System.out.println(symbol.codePoints().count());//as Josh Lee commented
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html?

Comment: Not every unicode codepoint can be represented in 1 `char`, so you _can_ get surrogate pairs sometimes, like you seem to be.

Comment: because some UTF-8 characters take more bytes than normal charachers(ASCII)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode

Comment: This maybe useful: http://www.tugay.biz/2016/07/stringlength-method-may-fool-you.html

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you're trying to handle Unicode in the broadest way possible, you should use built-in methods. Otherwise you're in for a world of pain.

Answer (score 1):

A Java String object is a sequence of `char`, which are UTF-16 values. To handle all of Unicode you need to look for the `codePoint` constructors and methods (which use `int` as the representation of a code point).

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{
    (byte)0xf0, (byte)0x93, (byte)0x81, (byte)0x98};
String s = new String(b, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(s.length());  // 2
System.out.println(s.codePoints().count());  // 1
```

Your particular character, U+13058, has the UTF-16 representation of 0xD80C 0xDC58.

As for the question of how to convert UTF-8 bytes to a String, the Java standard library can do that for you, whether directly calling the String constructor or when constructing an InputStreamReader.

Comment: Thank you. That brings some light, but for my code I still have 2 codePoints for some values.